# How can I know what app/software is launching a Virtual key?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, context-menu, popups

My Right Click Menu (Context Menu) keeps randomly popping up in my Windows 10.
Even if I don't do anything. I have tried all possible solutions. Nothing helps.
It starts right after installing windows10.

With mskey.exe I have been able to see that this is the key that is activated:

> Key: Application (make) - 0x5D

I've read online that it's a Virtual key VK_APPS (context menu).
How can I know what app/software is launching this key?

Answer (score 1):

1. Look in Task Manager, *Details* tab, for any unusual software. Sort on CPU usage, and look for non-zero use because this process must be consuming *some* time, though not necessarily much.
2. This does not seem like the proper behavior for legitimate software. Run a virus scan with an additional tool, such as a single scan with [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/solutions/virus-scanner). Do not install an anti-malware suite so as to make automatic scans, since that would interfere with with the already-installed anti-malware software. (One presumes you *do* have an antivirus, such as Windows Defender.)
3. The issue does not seem like one caused by Windows itself, but it would not hurt to perform checks and repairs on the OS with [SFC and DISM](https://www.techbout.com/repair-windows-system-files-using-sfc-dism-12162/).
4. If that fails, reinstall Windows 10 from a [**known valid ISO** from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), made via [Create Windows 10 installation media](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691209).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately before writing my question I have already tried all these things. No virus, no spyware (malwarebytes), nothing wrong SFC/DISM. Have reinstalled windows from scratch. The same problem. Even if I only disable the touchpad or mouse. Same problem when using a different mouse. The windows 10 version is an officially purchased version. Could not find anything strange in Task manager. :(

Comment: @Reman, Sorry my suggestions were not helpful. You've done thorough testing, and there's is only one more test I'd suggest: boot from a live USB, e.g., Ubuntu (https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/) or Hiren's Boot CD/USB (https://www.tomsguide.com/how-to/how-to-download-hirens-bootcd). If the issue persists, then you can be *sure* it's a hardware problem, such as the mouse/touchpad controller itself. If the context menu *does not* pop up, though, there's definitely a software/OS/malware problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I created a Mint Linux boot USB. The context menu does pop up again. I changed mouse, same problem. I changed usb port, same problem. I disabled touchpad, same problem. I disabled my mouse but not the touchpad, same problem.

Comment: Definitely a hardware issue, then. Has the PC ever gotten wet? It could be corrosion or conductive chemicals on the PCB, rather than a defective chip, and careful cleaning of the PCB, with power supply unplugged and battery removed, if laptop, using 91% or stronger isopropyl alcohol on a damp cloth or swab *might* help.

Comment: It has never gotten wet. Yes it is a laptop. Can it be the bios? The PC is from 2013 and not sustained anymore. Maybe the bios need an upgrade to win 10?

Comment: Unlikely to be BIOS -- how would BIOS cause random pop-up?